# Laravel MySQL how to order results in the same order as in whereIn clause

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two queries, the first one gives me an array of ids, that is in a specific order. Then that array of ids I pass it to the second query like so:

```
 Operation::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

But when I output the result of that query, the order has changed, if the array $ids was something like (4,2,6,9) which is the order I wanted the results to be in, the output will give me 2,4,6,9. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**MySQL** way of sorting with order same as in `where in` clause:

```
$ids; // array of ids
$placeholders = implode(',',array_fill(0, count($ids), '?')); // string for the query

Operation::whereIn('id', $ids)
   ->orderByRaw("field(id,{$placeholders})", $ids)->get();
```

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk You have solved my same problem of order by some of random values. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
$idsImploded = implode(',',$ids);
Operation::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByRaw("FIND_IN_SET('id','$idsImploded')")->get();
```

It's a problem where MySql doesn't return the result in the order you specify them, so you need to reorder them after that.

A similar solution can be found here: [avoid Sorting by the MYSQL IN Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195642/avoid-sorting-by-the-mysql-in-keyword)

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET' (SQL: select * from `operations` where `id` in (42, 3, 4, 37, 16, 38, 39, 14, 17) order by FIND_IN_SET(id,42,3,4,37,16,38,39,14,17 ))

Comment: Fixed. I forgot to add the ' ' to the FIND_IN_SET arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the sorting order in 4,2,6,9, you can fetch these rows, then use php to sort.

Comment: I need to be able to use eloquent later on to get more info from tables related to Operations, how can I sort the objet returned by that query without losing that capability?

Comment: As in, in my view I want to do $operations->event->name, where event is a related table and operations is what comes from the query in my question.

Comment: you can put all the info first then do sort

Comment: I'd rather not do all that on the view, I prefer the other solution, but I guess yours would work aswell